# can i apply filter in summarise_all?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am doing sum up for my data frame. My data frame looks like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F

1   1   1   1   4   2
2   2   5   6   9   9
3   1   7   1   2   4
4   9   6   5   6   6
5   4   7   9   1   5
6   9   9   7   5   7
7   6   1   6   7   8
8   8   3   4   3   6
9   9   4   6   1   1
```

I would love to sum up for each column, based on Link type. I can make it work with code:

```
df>-datafram%>%
summaries_all(sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```

And the output is :

```
A   B   C   D   E   F

45  49  43  45  38  48
```

but when I apply with filter:

```
summaries_all(sum(B<9),na.rm=TRUE),
```

the R said:

```
Error in is_fun_list(.funs) : object 'B' not found
```

I would love to apply filter to my summaries_all so that only sum all the numbers that b<9

Can you guys give me some hints please

Many thanks

Comment: use `filter(B < 9)` before summarising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a logical expression with 'B' to subset the values of each column and then do the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
datafram %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(-B), ~ sum(.[B < 9], na.rm = TRUE))
#   A  C  D  E  F
#1 26 24 27 26 34
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for helping me , the code is half worked...
I got sum for A and B , but for column C,D,E,F, i got 0

Comment: here is what i get:
{A B C D E F
26 22 0 0 0 0}

Comment: Based on your dataset, that is not possiblee

Comment: I am sorry I dont know whather I have some typo error or not, this is what i put into R:
  summarise_all( ~sum(.[B<9],na.rm=TRUE))
and i do get correct number for A and B, but for columne after B, they all 0

Comment: @BomberGay. Okay, I got the issue.  When you do the `summarise_all`, it is also updating the 'B'.  Instead you can skip 'B"

Comment: @BomberGay. I am guessing this to be a bug because it should do the calculation based on the original data instead of the updated

Comment: Thank you @Akrun, it worked!! Thanks a lot!! May i ask what is the meaning for "~sum" please?

Comment: @BomberGay. tilde `~` is a shorthand for anonymous function call `function(x) x` in tidyverse.  You can also use `list(~ `